# How to log execution of a nutch plugin

Tags: java, plugins, solr, nutch, web-crawler

I am working hard in building custom [nutch](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/) plugin with special requirements.

I found my plugin mentioned in `hadoop.log` but it was not relevant.

I added `LOG.debug("test")` and `LOG.info("test2")` in different places of my code and I wrote in `log4j.properties`

```
# Logging for development
log4j.logger.org.apache.nutch.parse.html=DEBUG
```

My question is: where can I find these messages, I've checked `hadoop.log` but I couldn't find anything?

How can I log / trace my java code? (I'm not using eclipse.)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your plugin has the class Variable

```
public static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(YourClass.class
        .getName());
```

And your called method has:

```
LOG.info("Your Logmessage");
```

And you have built your plugin and configured that Nutch uses your plugin when fetching/crawling/... then the message is logged in the hadoop.log.

When you built Nutch, does it say it is building your plugin?

If yes, you can check your your plugin configuration, which is deployed to NutchHome/runtime/local/conf/nutch-site.xml:

```
<property>
<name>plugin.includes</name>
<value>protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html)|yourplugin</value>
<description>The plugins which are used in every crawl ordered by call-  order</description>
</property>
```

If your plugin is configured in the runtime environment. If not change the configfile an rebuild Nutch. If that doesn't help, you can give me some more information.

Comment: I follow your instruction, added LOG  variable, put messages in different places, I can see nutch is building myplugin, I've configured nutch-site.xml correctly, trying to crawl again and then check th hodoop.log in runtime folder, cant find my message !   I'm implementing HtmlParseFilter ... mmm what kind of information do you need ?? Thanks

Comment: Hi Haya, what kind of Plugin do you want to create? A Parser, a IndexingFilter? You have to inherit the special Interfaces Nutch gives to you and then you have to configure them right in the plugin.xml of your plugin. Maybe you should post your Plugin structure (packages) and your plugin.xml file. Greetings jp

Comment: It is a parser (I want to extract special data from the page and index them), so my class is implementing HtmlParseFilter, and I've added this method: public ParseResult filter(Content content, ParseResult parseResult, HTMLMetaTags metaTags, DocumentFragment doc) {LOG.info("in filter method"); return parseResult;}             Note that I can find Myplugin name in the hadoop.log, so I think there is no problem with plugin.xml,,,, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved by this code

```
 import org.slf4j.Logger;
 import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
 public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.apache.nutch.parse.html");
```

Comment: also found that the seedlist (URLs) should be in this format http://www .site.com/ dont forget to write 'www'